# the server could not find the metric nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second for pods

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator, hpa

I installed the [kube-prometheus-0.9.0](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus), and want to deploy a sample application on which to test the Prometheus metrics autoscaling, with the following resource manifest file: (hpa-prome-demo.yaml)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hpa-prom-demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-demo
        image: cnych/nginx-vts:v1.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 50m
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hpa-prom-demo
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "80"
    prometheus.io/path: "/status/format/prometheus"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-server
  type: NodePort
```

For testing purposes, used a NodePort Service and luckly I can get the http repsonse after applying the deployment. Then I installed
Prometheus Adapter via Helm Chart by creating a new `hpa-prome-adapter-values.yaml` file to override the default Values values, as follows.

```yaml
rules:
  default: false
  custom:
  - seriesQuery: 'nginx_vts_server_requests_total'
    resources:
      overrides:
        kubernetes_namespace:
          resource: namespace
        kubernetes_pod_name:
          resource: pod
    name:
      matches: "^(.*)_total"
      as: "${1}_per_second"
    metricsQuery: (sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[1m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>))

prometheus:
  url: http://prometheus-k8s.monitoring.svc
  port: 9090
```

Added a rules rule and specify the address of Prometheus. Install Prometheus-Adapter with the following command.

```sh
$ helm install prometheus-adapter prometheus-community/prometheus-adapter -n monitoring -f hpa-prome-adapter-values.yaml
NAME: prometheus-adapter
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Jan 28 09:16:06 2022
NAMESPACE: monitoring
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
prometheus-adapter has been deployed.
In a few minutes you should be able to list metrics using the following command(s):

  kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Finally the adatper was installed successfully, and can get the http response, as follows.

```sh
$ kubectl get po -nmonitoring |grep adapter
prometheus-adapter-665dc5f76c-k2lnl    1/1     Running   0          133m

$ kubectl get --raw="/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "namespaces/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But it was supposed to be like this,

```json
$  kubectl get --raw="/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "namespaces/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pods/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Why I can't get the metrics `pods/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second`? as a result, below query was also failed.

```sh
 kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/*/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second" | jq .
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the metric nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second for pods
```

Anybody cloud please help? many thanks.

Comment: Can you try next request? `kubectl get --raw '/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pod/YourPodName/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second' | jq .`

Comment: prompt can't find the metric.   `Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the metric nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second for pod`

Comment: What components included in the [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus) have you installed ?
Could you please list all components with a command like `kubectl get pods -n monitoring` ?
What version of Kubernetes do you have ? You need to refer to the [Kubernetes compatibility matrix](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus#kubernetes-compatibility-matrix) in order to choose a compatible branch.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth knowing that using the [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus) repository, you can also install components such as **Prometheus Adapter for Kubernetes Metrics APIs**, so there is no need to install it separately with Helm.

I will use your `hpa-prome-demo.yaml` manifest file to demonstrate how to monitor `nginx_vts_server_requests_total` metrics.

---

First of all, we need to install Prometheus and Prometheus Adapter with appropriate configuration as described step by step below.

Copy the [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus) repository and refer to the [Kubernetes compatibility matrix](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus#kubernetes-compatibility-matrix) in order to choose a compatible branch:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus.git 
$ cd kube-prometheus
$ git checkout release-0.9
```

Install the `jb`, `jsonnet` and `gojsontoyaml` tools:

```
$ go install -a github.com/jsonnet-bundler/jsonnet-bundler/cmd/jb@latest
$ go install github.com/google/go-jsonnet/cmd/jsonnet@latest
$ go install github.com/brancz/gojsontoyaml@latest
```

Uncomment the `(import 'kube-prometheus/addons/custom-metrics.libsonnet') +` line from the `example.jsonnet` file:

```
$ cat example.jsonnet
local kp =
  (import 'kube-prometheus/main.libsonnet') +
  // Uncomment the following imports to enable its patches
  // (import 'kube-prometheus/addons/anti-affinity.libsonnet') +
  // (import 'kube-prometheus/addons/managed-cluster.libsonnet') +
  // (import 'kube-prometheus/addons/node-ports.libsonnet') +
  // (import 'kube-prometheus/addons/static-etcd.libsonnet') +
  (import 'kube-prometheus/addons/custom-metrics.libsonnet') +          <--- This line
  // (import 'kube-prometheus/addons/external-metrics.libsonnet') +
...
```

Add the following rule to the `./jsonnet/kube-prometheus/addons/custom-metrics.libsonnet` file in the `rules+` section:

```
      {
        seriesQuery: "nginx_vts_server_requests_total",
        resources: {
          overrides: {
            namespace: { resource: 'namespace' },
            pod: { resource: 'pod' },
          },
        },
        name: { "matches": "^(.*)_total", "as": "${1}_per_second" },
        metricsQuery: "(sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[1m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>))",
      },
```

After this update, the `./jsonnet/kube-prometheus/addons/custom-metrics.libsonnet` file should look like this:
**NOTE:** This is not the entire file, just an important part of it.

```
$ cat custom-metrics.libsonnet
// Custom metrics API allows the HPA v2 to scale based on arbirary metrics.
// For more details on usage visit https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter#quick-links

{
  values+:: {
    prometheusAdapter+: {
      namespace: $.values.common.namespace,
      // Rules for custom-metrics
      config+:: {
        rules+: [
          {
            seriesQuery: "nginx_vts_server_requests_total",
            resources: {
              overrides: {
                namespace: { resource: 'namespace' },
                pod: { resource: 'pod' },
              },
            },
            name: { "matches": "^(.*)_total", "as": "${1}_per_second" },
            metricsQuery: "(sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[1m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>))",
          },
...
```

Use the jsonnet-bundler update functionality to update the `kube-prometheus` dependency:

```
$ jb update
```

Compile the manifests:

```
$ ./build.sh example.jsonnet
```

Now simply use `kubectl` to install Prometheus and other components as per your configuration:

```
$ kubectl apply --server-side -f manifests/setup
$ kubectl apply -f manifests/
```

After configuring Prometheus, we can deploy a sample `hpa-prom-demo` Deployment:
**NOTE:** I've deleted the annotations because I'm going to use a [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#related-resources) to describe the set of targets to be monitored by Prometheus.

```
$ cat hpa-prome-demo.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hpa-prom-demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-demo
        image: cnych/nginx-vts:v1.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 50m
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hpa-prom-demo
  labels:
    app: nginx-server
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-server
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Next, create a `ServiceMonitor` that describes how to monitor our NGINX:

```
$ cat servicemonitor.yaml
kind: ServiceMonitor
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
metadata:
  name: hpa-prom-demo
  labels:
    app: nginx-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-server
  endpoints:
  - interval: 15s
    path: "/status/format/prometheus"
    port: http
```

After waiting some time, let's check the `hpa-prom-demo` logs to make sure that it is scrapped correctly:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hpa-prom-demo-bbb6c65bb-49jsh   1/1     Running   0          35m

$ kubectl logs -f hpa-prom-demo-bbb6c65bb-49jsh
...
10.4.0.9 - - [04/Feb/2022:09:29:17 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3771 "-" "Prometheus/2.29.1" "-"
10.4.0.9 - - [04/Feb/2022:09:29:32 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3771 "-" "Prometheus/2.29.1" "-"
10.4.0.9 - - [04/Feb/2022:09:29:47 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3773 "-" "Prometheus/2.29.1" "-"
10.4.0.9 - - [04/Feb/2022:09:30:02 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3773 "-" "Prometheus/2.29.1" "-"
10.4.0.9 - - [04/Feb/2022:09:30:17 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3773 "-" "Prometheus/2.29.1" "-"
10.4.2.12 - - [04/Feb/2022:09:30:23 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3773 "-" "Prometheus/2.29.1" "-"
...
```

Finally, we can check if our metrics work as expected:

```
$ kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/" | jq . | grep -A 7 "nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second"
      "name": "pods/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
--
      "name": "namespaces/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },

$ kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/*/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second" | jq .
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/%2A/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Pod",
        "namespace": "default",
        "name": "hpa-prom-demo-bbb6c65bb-49jsh",
        "apiVersion": "/v1"
      },
      "metricName": "nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "timestamp": "2022-02-04T09:32:59Z",
      "value": "533m",
      "selector": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**ENV**:

1. helm install all Prometheus charts from  `prometheus-community   https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-chart`
2. k8s cluster enabled by docker for mac

**Solution**:
I met the same problem, from Prometheus UI, i found it had `namespace` label and no `pod` label in metrics as below.

```
nginx_vts_server_requests_total{code="1xx", host="*", instance="10.1.0.19:80", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace="default", node="docker-desktop", service="hpa-prom-demo"}
```

I thought Prometheus may **NOT** use `pod` as a label, so i checked Prometheus config and found:

```
121       - action: replace
122         source_labels:
123         - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
124         target_label: node
```

then searched
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/ and do the similar thing as below under every `__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name` i searched（ie. 2 places)

```
125       - action: replace
126         source_labels:
127         - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
128         target_label: pod
```

after a while, the configmap reloaded, UI and API could find `pod` label

```
$ kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq                                    
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "pods/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "namespaces/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```