# Why I got nothing from cmd "kubectl get --raw '/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespace/default/pods/*/' | jq"

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

What might be root cause that I got nothing from below command?

```sh
$ kubectl get --raw '/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespace/default/pods/*/' | jq
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

I checked the '/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1' as follow.

```sh
kubectl get --raw '/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1' | jq
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "namespaces/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the adapter was normal which was deployed via [Helm Chart](https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts).

```sh
kubectl get apiservice | grep adapter
v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io          monitoring/prometheus-adapter   True        11m
```

Anybody can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like there is no pods related metrics in '/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1' response.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes do you use? Is it bare metal installation or on the cloud provider?

Comment: but there is the pod. And I can query the metrics via prometheus webui. @YuweiHE.

Comment: I use kubernetes 1.19. @anarxz

Answer (score 2):

```
kubectl get --raw '/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/*/metrics/nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second' | jq
```

Did you try the namespace metric `nginx_vts_server_requests_per_second` you pasted from the kubernetes discovery information?

You may need to change the prometheus adapter's configuration to include pods related metrics.

The [prometheus-adapter walkthrough docs](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md) may be useful to you.

Comment: Yes, I tried and got the result. but it confused me a lot. why the namespace was changed, isn't it be the default namespace? Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: I created the prometheus adapter in the way like below links.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888585/the-server-could-not-find-the-metric-nginx-vts-server-requests-per-second-for-po